# Elementor stucks after adding a button to the column

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Issue
-Add a button to the column
-Update
-Reload the page
Now the page won't reload, it'll be stuck on the Elementor logo screen.
But If I remove the button it works fine.

I have tried the following solutions but they didn't work

```
Removing all the plugins
Increasing Memory Limit to 256M and 512M
Reinstalling Elementor
Rollbaking version
Updating WordPress
```

Elementor v 3.2.2 & Pro v3.2.2
Kindly help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5kCw.png)

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION!

Go to Elementor >Settings >Advanced >Switch Editor Loader Method > Enable

I figured out it was a Server problem. In my case it was GoDaddy.